# Firestore index for user created fields

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore as a database for my react-native app.

I am executing following query on my firestore:

```
 const docRef = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('meetings')
        .where('visitors.' + user, '==', true)
        .where('meetingTime', '>', yesterday)
        .get()
```

I get an error message telling me that i require and index, with this errormessage is a link to create the index automatically. Following this link shows next image: 
[image]

Now i really don't want visitors.'user@test_be' to be hardcoded in the index because the visitors object is dynamic, more users can be added as visitors and then the index does not work anymore.

My meeting documents looks like this:

[image]

How can i make an index that makes sure i can execute my query?
Or should i restructure my database?
Or is this just not possible in firestore?

Comment: It would be better if you used an english version of your screenshot instead of dutch.

Comment: Tnx did not see that. Updated accordingly

Comment: Something seems off about the user email address there. The backticks shouldn't be there. My guess is that those are causing the problem, because Firestore should already be indexing the visitors array (see [this docs page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Wow tnx a lot for that doc page, i must'v read over it or something. Anyway it fixed my problem. i'll update my answer with the new method

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it thanks thanks to frank van puffelen guiding me to the correct docs

I changed my firebase data structure as follows:

```
meetings
  meeting
    meetingName: 'meeting 1'
    meetingTime: 1524823200
    visitors: 
      user@user_be: true
```

Changed to

```
meetings
      meeting
        meetingName: 'meeting 1'
        visitors: 
          user@user_be: 1524823200
```

then in my query i do:

```
const docRef = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('meetings')
        .where('visitors.' + user, '>', 0)
        .where('visitors.' + user, '>', yesterday)
        .get()
```

Link to fix: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays